# Using Terraform module output as input to local-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to define a module testing framework for terraform and my approach is to use Pester, called from a local-exec provisioner in order to verify build is correct.

To this end I was hoping to be able to use output from the module, e.g:

```
output "windows_ip_address" {
  value = module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip
}
```

... as an input for a local-exec provisioner. e.g:

```
module "windowsservers" {
  source              = "../../"
  vm_hostname         = "host${random_id.ip_dns.hex}-windows" // line can be removed if only one VM module per resource group
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  is_windows_image    = true
  admin_username      = var.admin_username
  admin_password      = var.admin_password
  vm_os_simple        = "WindowsServer"
  vnet_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
}

resource "null_resource" "run-pestertest" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    #command     = "..\\test_azurerm_compute.ps1 -vmhostname test -vmip ${module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip}"
    command = "echo ${module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip}"
    interpreter  = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
  depends_on = [module.windowsservers]
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

...but i'm getting:

```
Error: Invalid template interpolation value: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

I thought by using depends_on i'd be able to force terraform to graph it out in such a way that the "windowsserver" module would be inacted prior to null_resource - but I think maybe there is something fundamentally incorrect with what i'm doing!

Thanks
Dan

Comment: This `output` is from the same module or another module?

Comment: Hi Matt - it's the module called in the configuration above - it resides in a folder structure two levels above.

Comment: The error sounds like it might be coming from somewhere else. What happens if you remove the `null_resource` and run it? And what happens if instead you replace the `null_resource` with an output with value `module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip`?

Comment: I have `module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip` as an output value - and if i comment out the null_resource it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize if this is a silly question, but have you verified the module output you want to use (module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip) is in fact typed as a string? Perhaps it's a list, or something else .. You can try "forcing" it to be a string in a locals block and see if that either fixes the error or changes it to indicate perhaps the output type isn't actually a string ..

```
locals = {
module_private_ip = "${tostring(module.windowsservers.network_interface_private_ip)}"
}
```

I only mention the locals block because it looks like you use it in multiple places, and using the locals means only one place it's used, and once place that could be spitting out the error about invalid type.

I've also used the locals block as a trick to deal with dependencies between modules as TF doesn't always seem to handle that well..

and I apologize for posting as an "answer", but I don't have the karma to post comments yet :)

Comment: Thanks - not a silly question at all - there was indeed a data mismatch between my module outputs and subsequent expected inputs.  I fixed it in the short term by referencing the first (and only) element in the object using [0] - but will do some reading!